# Combine the values of a certain property based on the value of a different property in a List of Objects in C#?

Tags: c#, list, linq

Currently I have a `List<OrderModel>`. `OrderModel` is a class that contains two properties: `OrderId` and `Total`. In this case `OrderId` is NOT unique. I want to combine the values of the `Total` property where `OrderId` matches.

I have a solution, but I want to know if there is a better way (speaking in terms of performance) of accomplishing this task. Here is what I am currently doing:

As I fill my `List<OrderModel>` object I also add the `OrderId` to a `List<long>`. So now that I have two lists.

```
foreach (var id in orderIdList.Distinct())
{
    var orders = orderModelList.Where(l => l.OrderId == id).ToList();
    if (orders.Count() > 1)
    {
        var firstOrder = orders.FirstOrDefault();
        orders.Remove(firstOrder);
        foreach (var order in orders)
        {
        firstOrder.Total += order.Total;
        orderModelList.Remove(order);                    
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing a lot of useless enumerations in your version. Assuming you have a list of orders, you can use `GroupBy` to do most of the filtering:

```
var orderModelList = orders.GroupBy(o => o.Id)
    .Select(group => new OrderModel
    {
        Id = group.Key,
        Total = group.Sum(o => o.Total)
    })
    .ToList();
```